# Python 3 unpack tuples using map

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

I have a list of tuples:

```
myList = [('name1', data1), ('name2', data2), ... ]
```

The data are just `ndarrays` but that's not important. I want to unpack this as:

```
names, data = map(f, myList)
```

If I write: `f = lambda x: [x[0], x[1]]` then

```
name1, data1 = f(myList[k])
```

works for any `k` but `map` won't; it says there are too many values to unpack.

Since I am doing this unpacking in a long list of computation in a function, I would prefer sticking to map/lambda or a one-liner instead of resorting to writing a new function `def vectorize ...` (which I did but seemed like a hack).

Comment: What's wrong with `zip()`?

Comment: `names,data = zip(*myList)`

Comment: Thanks! I thought zip was for creating tuples out of list, I didn't know it did the reverse too.

Comment: Cool, I just noticed that the python doc does mention this: `zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list`. I was going to suggest `keys, vals = dict(l).keys(), dict(l).values()`, but `zip()` is totally better for this specific question. Perhaps my solution has its place elsewhere.